# Can I set the start number for image sequence output?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion

I am using [ffmpeg to convert from video to an image sequence](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence) as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm image-%03d.png
```

The first image is labelled `001`, but I want it to be labelled `098`. Is it possible to set that value in the ffmpeg invocation?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [image sequence muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) has a [start number option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-5), so

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm -start_number 98 image-%03d.png
```

Comment: Does this still work? The arg is being ignored for me

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: I had to put the `-start_number` flag before the `-i` flag for it to get parsed.

Comment: Moving it before `-i` results in an error: `Option start_number not found.` after `-i` it just gets ignored.

Comment: @shockburner Simply reordering the arguments actually made it work on ffmpeg 4.4.2 built with Apple clang-1300.0.29.30, kudos!